# Where is Spark's LogisticRegression doing data standardization?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, logistic-regression

I am looking into Spark's `ml.LogisticRegression` to find where and how it standardize its input dataset.

However, when I check [spark/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/LogisticRegression.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/LogisticRegression.scala), I expected something like

```
if(standardization){
    scaled_dataset = do_standardization(old_dataset)
}
```

Then I can check which method(min-max, zscore or something else) is used. However I found no evidence that LR is using standardization. I know with the current LBFGS optimizer, it doesn't matter whether to do standardization, but since spark still provide the `setStandardization` option and says that using standardization will provide better convergence, I'd like to know where and how does it do standardization.

From the current code, I found set `standardization` or not only affects how to do regularizaiton. And seems that spark multiply coeff with `featuresStd` rather than do z-score to dataset.

Comment: The GLM docs referenced in the Spark source might be helpful (https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/Glmnet_Vignette.pdf): "standardize is a logical flag for x variable standardization, prior to fitting the model sequence. The coefficients are always returned on the original scale". Some practical tutorials, albeit in R: https://statisticaloddsandends.wordpress.com/2018/11/15/a-deep-dive-into-glmnet-standardize/ and https://think-lab.github.io/d/205/#5